# need to create dynamic form in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to create dynamic fields in javascript.I  create simple text box It works fine.I want to display with div tag and need to create selectbox with javascript.I want to create form given below in javascript

```html
<form method="POST">
  <table border=1> 
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-4">First  Name:</label>
 <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="V1_Fname" >
           
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-4">Last   Name:</label>
 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input type="text" name="V1_Lname" ">
                 </div>
           </div>
       </div>  
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Relation to Member:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select size="1" name="V1_Relation">
                <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="SP">Spouse</option>
            <option value="Son">Son</option>
             <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
            <option  value="F">Father</option>
           <option   value="M">Mother</option>
             <option value="MIL">Mother-in-   value="OTH">Other</option>
            </select>
           
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      
      </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

I tried First name ,last name and Age in javascript.

```
function create(sel_value) {
  // alert(sel_value);
  for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append($("<div/>", {
      id: 'head'
    }).append($("<h3/>").text("Visitor" + i)), $("<input/>", {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name' + i,
      name: 'firstName_' + i
    }), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name' + i,
      name: 'lastName_' + i
    }), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
      placeholder: 'Age' + i,
      type: 'text',
      name: 'Age_' + i
    }), $("<br/>"), $("<hr/>"), $("<br/>")))
  }
}
```